# What are the methods for predicting an ordinal variable?

Tags: r, random-forest, ordinal-data

I am trying to predict age group for each individuals.  I have a large data with 63 variables and about 50.000 observations. But I dont know what each variable mean, I have only values. To predict, I used randomForest and got about 63% accuracy. So, what methods I should use to predict an ordinal variable?

Comment: How many groups are there? Assuming you used classification trees as the methodological core of your RF, another approach would be to plug an ordinal logistic regression into the "core" of the RF framework and rerunning it. This would test for any improvement in predictive accuracy relative to trees. Another workaround would be to use the midpoint for each age bucket and treating the resulting scale as "continuous," this opens up a much wider class of possible models.

Comment: There are seven groups (0-6) but I dont know something about ages of each group. What do you mean to put logistic regression into the core of the RF? How can I realize this? For RF I used library randomForest in R.

Comment: You don't even know what the age buckets mean or refer to?The standard approach for RFs is to fit a series of "mini-CARTs." This is the RF algorithm Breiman originally developed. But, one can "plug in" any multivariate method one wishes, creating variants of "RFs" as a function of the method used. In your case, it could be called "random mini-models using ordinal logistic regression." These are also known as "divide and conquer" algorithms...see, e.g., this paper by Chen and Xie *A SPLIT-AND-CONQUER APPROACH FOR ANALYSIS OF EXTRAORDINARILY LARGE DATA*...